# AWS datapipeline success based triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create a data pipeline with two activities. how can I set a condition if activity1 is success, trigger activity2 otherwise stop/still be in waiting state activity2. can I rerun activity2 manually after some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your second activity: 
"dependsOn" : { "ref" : "id of your first activity" }

You can rerun activity2 manually from the console.